# Highchart, edit data from function call with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, function-call

I simply wanna change data series in highcharts via a function call. But it seems i can't access it. I get that "series" are undefined. I've also tried to using something similar as the 'button-click' method (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append/) unsuccessfully.

Any help are greatly appreciated
BR Kristian

```
var mainchart;
function addGraphData(a) {
  mainchart.series[0].addPoint(a);
}
$(function () { 
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      defaultSeriesType: 'line',
      events: {
        load : function () {
          mainchart = this; // `this` is the reference to the chart
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Kobber (KJ-040)'
    },
    xAxis: {
        text: 'Dato'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
        text: 'Resultater'
        }
    },
    series: [{
      //name: 'Metall data',
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
  });
})
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    });


    // the button action
    var i = 0;
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.series[0].addPoint(50 * (i % 3));
        i += 1;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button" class="autocompare">Add point</button>
```

Comment: Where are you calling your `addGraphData()` function ?

Comment: Im actually first calling a createGraph() function on window-load, then im calling addGraphData(). I wanna call that function globally in certain special events. How can i do that? Keep in mind that im completely neewbie in jquery.

Comment: Just call createGraph() and then call addGraphData() for each points you want to add. I really don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just not calling the function you defined. I took your code and made a JSFiddle with and it works. I simply added:

```
 $('#button').click(function () {        
    addGraphData(Math.random()*100);
});
```

See a working JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Lfnbapn7/2/

Comment: So the problem is where im calling the function? I wanna call the addGraphData() function globally, independent from buttons or mouse clicks? how can i do that?

Comment: I don't understand. How many points do you want to add ? If just one, then you can call `addGraphData(150)` for example.

Comment: Im sorry if im unclear. I just wanna be able to edit the chart dynamically from wherever using a function-call, like if i have two input-fields that gets their values in a "correct range". Then i wanna add a value to the chart?

Comment: Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfnbapn7/6/ Here i get the same error im struggling with.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfnbapn7/14/ You weren't using `setInterval()` function correctly.